# What type of code is this?

Tags: cipher

Xijtqfs, eje zpv hfu ju?
Zft Cptt. If epfto'u lopx ju't hpof.
Hppe, Xibu bcpvu Kbnft boe Iboobi?
Kbnft jt bmsjhiu, uibu ofx Tibqf-Tijgujfs Qspupuzqf jt hsfbu. Iboobi jt opx cfjoh dpmmfdufe.
Hppe, uibu't hppe.
Xibu bcpvu Wjoojf?
Xip't Wjoojf?
Wjoojf Boefstpo.
Xibu bcpvu ijn?
If jt ifmqjoh Iboobi, if lopxt bcpvu vt.
Dbquvsf ijn upp uifo. Jg if jt up dpnf up uif wjsvt, zpvs dpwfs xjmm cf cmpxo.
Hpuub Cptt, ep uif tbnf uijoh bt Kbnft up cpui Iboobi boe Wjoojf?
Zft, ju xjmm ijef uifn gps uif Wjsvt.
Pl. J hpu up npwf. J xjmm sfqpsu jo xjui xifo J ibwf dbquvsfe cpui Iboobi boe Wjoojf.

Comment: Is this really a puzzle? I mean you have to tryout just some common cipher methods, nothing exclusive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a

> ROT1 cipher

and it says

> Whisper, did you get it? Yes Boss. He doesn't know it's gone. Good, What about James and Hannah? James is alright, that new Shape-Shiftier Prototype is great. Hannah is now being collected. Good, that's good. What about Vinnie? Who's Vinnie? Vinnie Anderson. What about him? He is helping Hannah, he knows about us. Capture him too then. If he is to come to the virus, your cover will be blown. Gotta Boss, do the same thing as James to both Hannah and Vinnie? Yes, it will hide them for the Virus. Ok. I got to move. I will report in with when I have captured both Hannah and Vinnie.

To decrypt

> Shift every letter back by 1 in the alphabet.

To generate this quickly

> I used [this website](https://www.rot13.com/) with the ROT25 setting.